# Linq to SQL Source in Microsoft ReferenceSource

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, reference-source

I google and look in [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) but I can't find source of LINQ to SQL where LINQ queries converted to SQL statments. Is there any one who knows it?

for example:

```
from item in Users
select item
```

Converted to:

```
SELECT [t0].[UserID], [t0].[Username], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName], [t0].[IsSuperUser], [t0].[AffiliateId], [t0].[Email], [t0].[DisplayName], [t0].[UpdatePassword]
FROM [Users] AS [t0]
```

How? I want to see source of this behavior in [DotnetFramwork source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Look at the classes in the `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient` namespace in the `System.Data.Linq` assembly.  In particular, one of the SqlProvider classes, you'll likely find what you're looking for there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [DbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand.aspx) off of the datacontext. It takes an IQueryable.
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetCommand(System.Linq.IQueryable)

Summary:
Represents an SQL statement or stored procedure to execute against a data source. Provides a base class for database-specific classes that represent commands.

```
public void GetSqlCommand()
{
    const string sc2 = @"Server=SQLServerName;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;";

    using (var dc = new DataContext(sc2))
    {
        var query = dc.GetTable<Users>()
            .Join(dc.GetTable<Phone>(),
                x => x.UserId,
                y => y.LastUserId,
                (x, y) => new { User = x, Phone = y }).Select(x => x);

            DbCommand command = dc.GetCommand(query);

            Assert.IsNotNull(command.CommandText);
    }
}
```

Then it gives you something like this

```
SELECT [t0].[UserId], [t0].[Login], [t0].[FullName], [t0].[LastUserId], [t0].[LastDateTime], [t1].[PhoneId], [t1].[PhoneNumber], [t1].[LastUserId] AS [LastUserId2], [t1].[LastDateTime] AS [LastDateTime2]
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Phone] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[UserId]) = [t1].[LastUserId]
```

Update you seem to want the code that's used by the framework for building the SQL from the query. 
Here is a link to the MSFT reference code for the SQLProvider I think you can find your answer in there. 
[SQLProvider](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/SqlClient/SqlProvider.cs,af7e5c96fbbe0428)

Look at this method it returns the Query Info of the Query expression you passed along.
Query Info has the resulting CommandText I mentioned above.

```
internal QueryInfo[] BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations) {.. calls the private BuildQuery..}

private QueryInfo[] BuildQuery(ResultShape resultShape, Type resultType, SqlNode node, ReadOnlyCollection<Me.SqlParameter> parentParameters, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations) {...}
```

......

```
internal class QueryInfo {
    SqlNode query;
    string commandText;
    ReadOnlyCollection<SqlParameterInfo> parameters;
    ResultShape resultShape;
    Type resultType;

    internal QueryInfo(SqlNode query, string commandText, ReadOnlyCollection<SqlParameterInfo> parameters, ResultShape resultShape, Type resultType) {
        this.query = query;
        this.commandText = commandText;
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.resultShape = resultShape;
        this.resultType = resultType;
    }
    internal SqlNode Query {
        get { return this.query; }
    }
    internal string CommandText {
        get { return this.commandText; }
    }
    internal ReadOnlyCollection<SqlParameterInfo> Parameters {
        get { return this.parameters; }
    }
    internal ResultShape ResultShape {
        get { return this.resultShape; }
    }
    internal Type ResultType {
        get { return this.resultType; }
    }
}
```

You'll see the the GetCommand also calls the [Build Query](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/SqlClient/SqlProvider.cs,af7e5c96fbbe0428) Method to generate the the SQL and then get the command text from the first query

```
DbCommand IProvider.GetCommand(Expression query) 
{
    this.CheckDispose();
    this.CheckInitialized();
    if (query == null) {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("query");
    }
    this.InitializeProviderMode();
    SqlNodeAnnotations annotations = new SqlNodeAnnotations();
    QueryInfo[] qis = this.BuildQuery(query, annotations);
    QueryInfo qi = qis[qis.Length - 1];
    DbCommand cmd = this.conManager.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = qi.CommandText;
    cmd.Transaction = this.conManager.Transaction;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = this.commandTimeout;
    AssignParameters(cmd, qi.Parameters, null, null);
    return cmd;
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want the query string that is generated, but rather locate the code that generates it.

Comment: I just notice that, and updated the answer to include the link to the SqlProvider BuildQuery method that I think may help him.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the class that looking for is the [`SqlFormatter`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/SqlClient/Query/SqlFormatter.cs) class.  It will take a tree of [`SqlNode`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/SqlClient/Common/SqlNode.cs)s and converts it to a database query string using a visitor.

The node tree itself appears to be created by the factory methods in the [`SqlFactory`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/SqlClient/Common/SqlFactory.cs) class.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an sql profiler using sql server management studio to know the exact query conversion.

Comment: I know but i don't want to see the generated output. i want to see the source in dotnetframework..